# how to convert/integrate shopify cdn to bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, shopify, e-commerce

good day guys, i am new to web development, so apperntly, i got a work to design an ecommerce site for a client. the client wants something similar to [www.gallerydept.com](http://www.gallerydept.com) . But when i used inspect, i noticed the cdn is shopify's and not bootstrap and i'm only familiar with bootstrap.

how can i convert or intergrate bootstrap?

or what is the best suggestion or advice you can give me?

**(please remember i'm new to web dev)**

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion would be - **Don't use bootstrap within shopify**.

Reason - Bootstrap has their own set of customizations and shopify's depends upon the theme you are using. Let's consider two scenarios:

1. For example, you want to create a modal popup and you directly use the bootstrap's library for the same. The look and feel will be different and then you would add your own CSS to override that - problematic thing.
2. Second scenario, you integrate bootstrap's cdn into shopify then all the other components styling will get affected like buttons, navbar, hrefs etc. So the flow is bootstrap's css overrided your shopify theme css and then you will override both in order to get back to the original - shortly it will become unmanageable.

But after all this I am not saying don't go ahead with this, what I have seen some people doing is utilizing only bootstrap's flexbox system to manage responsiveness in custom shopify pages (which is a good technique because bootstrap's flexbox system is pretty great). So basically what they do is take bootstrap's CSS file and remove all CSS tags not pertaining to the flexbox system and use that leftover CSS file.

And answering your doubt, what you should do now is - go with native HTML/CSS. You get stuck somewhere, SO that doubt/get the code by inspecting the website you have.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is using themes so you can start looking into tutorials on how to create themes for Shopify. Bootstrap is only controlling the look and feel of the website which is what you do. Shoppify will control the entire ecommerce functionality. So you can use Bootstrap inside the Shopify theme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using LIQUID to code anything in Shopify and be sure not to use SCSS only CSS

Comment: SCSS can also be used, it depends on the theme - how it is developed.